# How do i work with pre-compiled libraries in cython?

Tags: python, compilation, cython

I'm trying to compile a quick extension for a module that was pre-compiled on install (`.pyd`). Below is a simplistic example of what i'm trying to do. Given `foo.pyd`:

### baz.pxd

```
from foo.bar cimport Bar

cdef class Baz(Bar):
    pass
```

### baz.pyx

```
cdef class Baz(Bar):
    def __init__(self, *a, **k):
        ...
```

### setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension

extensions = [Extension('baz', ['baz.pyx',], libraries=['foo.pyd',])]
setup(name='baz', ext_modules=cythonize(extensions))
```

I've tried many variations of the above, to no avail.

Comment: What does "no avail" mean?  Are you getting an error message?  What does it say? Which line of code is causing the error message?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: With this particular try, cython seems to want to find `foo.pXd`; ignoring the real `foo.pyd`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cimport` is for C/C++ APIs (functions, structs, classes) and reads from `.pxd` files, which are the Cython counterpart to C/C++ headers. If you don't have a `.pxd` for the `foo` library at compile-time, you cannot `cimport` from it. Python extension modules (`.pyd` on Windows, `.so` on Linux) typically don't have C APIs at all: they only contain externally visible symbols that allow the Python module importer to recognize their contents as a Python module.

Also, if you want to get a Python class (even one implemented as an extension type) from a module, you need to `import` it. I don't think a `cdef class` is allowed to inherit from such a class, though.

Comment: Thanks, larsmans. But it sounds like you're saying this can't be done. I'd have to write it in python?

Comment: @NoobSaibot It can't be done, probably, and you need to use an `import` instead of `cimport`. Whether you should do it in Python or Cython depends on the rest of the code, but you're not going to get a big speedup here.